# Applying Ito formula to Ito process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I would like to simplify the expression

$\left(\phi(s_{1})\cdot(X_{s_{1}}-X_{s_{2}})+\phi(s_{2})\cdot(X_{s_{2}}-X_{s_{3}})+\ldots+\phi(s_{n-1})\cdot(X_{s_{n-1}}-X_{s_{n}})\right)^{2}$

where $X_{t}$ is an Ito process, $\phi\in C^{\infty}$ and $s_{1}\geq s_{2}\ldots\geq s_{n}$.
How can I apply Ito formula in order to simplify the above expression? More precisely I would like to get rid of the $^{2}$.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this but this is a great example of a well written question! Good job! +1

Comment: I doubt you can simply further, if there is no any other conditions given. For example, Is $X$ a martingale, or does it have independent increatments? Note that, Ito's isometry applies to expectation only.

Comment: As I have written, $X$ is an Ito process, i.e. $X_{t}=\int_{0}^{t}a_{s}ds+\int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{s}dW_{s}$ and $W$ is a standard BM.

Comment: This is a discrete stochastic integral with respect to $X$. Apply Ito's formula on $f(x)=x^2$.